# Binding TextField to the ListView item

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I recently started working with TornadoFX and Kotlin and I'm stuck in bindings stuff.

I can add new items and delete them. `contributors` list gets new items, but I can't edit the content of it's items. If I don't use `bind(itemProperty())` I can edit textfields, but `contributors` list doesn't not update. If I use this binding, then I can't edit textfields.

In the main view I open modal window like this

MainView.kt

```
class MainView : View("Main") {
    override val root = VBox()
    private val viewModel by inject<MainViewModel>()

    init {
        with(root) {
            button("Edit") {
                action {                                             
                    find<ContributorFragment>(                                                
                        mapOf(ContributorFragment::contributors to 
                            viewModel.contributorProperty)).openModal()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ContributorFragment.kt

```
class ContributorFragment: Fragment() {
    val contributors: ObservableList<String>? by param()

    fieldset {
        field {
            listview(contributors) {
                cellFormat {
                    graphic = hbox {
                        textfield {
                        bind(itemProperty())
                }

                button("Delete") {
                    action {
                        contributors?.remove(it)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }

     fieldset {
         field {
             button("Add") {
                 action {
                     contributors?.add("")

                 }
             }
             button("Save") {
                 action {
                     close()
                 }
             }
          }
      }
}
```

MainViewModel.kt

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {
    var contributorProperty = bind { model.contributorProperty }
}
```

MainModel.kt

```
class MainModel {
    private var contributor: ObservableList<String> by property()
    val contributorProperty = getProperty(MainModel::contributor)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to pass a view model to another UI component using parameters, simply inject it into the `ContributorFragment`:

```
val viewModel: MyViewModel by inject()
```

Now you can access `viewModel.contributors` in a more natural way and remove that clutter from your code.

You have some weird naming in `MainViewModel` which suggests you're binding a view model property inside another view model? Maybe I misunderstand, but it looks strange.

I think you could benefit from this screencast about master/detail operations in TornadoFX:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1G1OYBRDSBs

About the non-updating issue: I'd suggest wrapping the strings in a model object with an observable property for the string. Without it, there is no way for them to update. Remember, a String is not passed by reference so even if you change the string in the TextField, you're not operating on the same instance you have in your list.

Comment: Thank you @Edvin Syse for reply. I've updated my answer by specifying classes to better understand the structure. I'm using one model and one view model. The video you sent was great. But it shows how to bind object and its properties to textfields. What about list and its dynamically added items. Can I bind those to textfields?

Comment: Yes, you can/should use a ListCellFragment in this case, see https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part2/Advanced%20Data%20Controls.html#listcellfragment

Comment: Thanks @Edvin Syse, ListCellFragment did it's job.